# Unsure how to fix my error for my matrices code, out of bounds errors on static arrays

Tags: arrays, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception

I am attempting to create a code that will fill two matrices based off of user entered code and then to use those matrices to add them subtract them transpose the first matrix and to also multiply them; however, I keep getting an out of bounds exception on line 18 which is `matrix1[m][n] = matrix[m][n];`. Also, I do not understand how to create the bounds for a public array using the user entered variables. Any help would be wonderful
PS: I'm really sorry if it is something really easy an I am being dumb and also I tried my hardest to format this correctly please don't get angry if I messed something up.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {
private int m,n,p,q,c,d,e,f,sum = 0,a,b;
int matrix1[][] = new int[m][n];
int matrix2[][]= new int [m][n];
public Matrix(){

}
//this portion is meant to fill the arrays matrix1 and matrix2 to be used later
public void fillarray(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix A");
      m = in.nextInt();
      n = in.nextInt();
      //out of bounds error here when attempting to declare length of rows and columns
      int matrix [][]= new int [m][n];
      matrix1[m][n] = matrix[m][n];

      System.out.println("Enter the elements of matrix A");

      for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ){
         for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ){
           matrix1[c][d] = in.nextInt();
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix A");
      p = in.nextInt();
      q = in.nextInt();
      //same out of bounds error here
      matrix2[p][q] = matrix2[p][q];

      System.out.println("Enter the elements of matrix B");

      for ( e = 0 ; e < p ; c++ ){
         for ( f = 0 ; f < q ; d++ ){
           matrix2[e][f] = in.nextInt();
         }
      }
}
//meant to transpose the array
    public void getTranspose(){
        int transpose[][] = new int[n][m];

          for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
          {
             for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )               
                transpose[d][c] = matrix1[c][d];
          }

          System.out.println("Transpose of entered matrix: ");

          for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
          {
             for ( d = 0 ; d < m ; d++ )
                   System.out.print(transpose[c][d]+"\t");

             System.out.print("\n");
          }
       }
    //meant to add the two matrices and find the sum
    public void addMatrix(){
          int sum[][] = new int[m][n];

          for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ){
              for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ){
                  sum[c][d] = matrix1[c][d] + matrix2[c][d];
              }
          }
          System.out.println("Sum of entered matrices: ");
          for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++)
          {
             for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ){
                System.out.print(sum[c][d]+"\t");
             }
             System.out.println();
          }
    }
    //meant to subtract the two matrices and find the difference
    public void subtractMatrix(){
        int sum[][] = new int[m][n];
        for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ){
              for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ){
                  sum[c][d] = matrix1[c][d] - matrix2[c][d];
              }
          }
        System.out.println("Differences of entered matrices: ");
          for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ){
             for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ){
                System.out.print(sum[c][d]+"\t");
             }
             System.out.println();
          }

    }
    //meant to multiply the two matrices and if the sizes do not match then explain why
    public void multiplyMatrix(){
        int multiply[][] = new int[m][q];
        if ( n != p ){
             System.out.println("Matrices with entered orders can't be multiplied with each other.");
             for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ){
                for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ ){   
                   for ( int k = 0 ; k < p ; k++ ){
                      sum = sum + matrix1[c][k]*matrix2[k][d];
                   }

                   multiply[c][d] = sum;
                   sum = 0;
                }
             }

             System.out.println("Product of entered matrices:-");

             for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ) {
                for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ ){
                   System.out.print(multiply[c][d]+"\t");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
             }

        }
    }
```

}

Here is my test program:

```
public class MatrixTest { 
     public static void main (String[] args){
         Matrix a = new Matrix(); 
         a.fillarray(); 
         a.getTranspose(); 
         a.addMatrix();
         a.subtractMatrix();
         a.multiplyMatrix(); 
     } 
}
```